# Azure Data Factory finding "malformed" records in valid JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm developing an ADF pipeline that reads in a JSON file from ADLS, removes two entities that I don't need, and writes the resulting file back to ADLS. This requires a data flow, but functionality wise this is simple stuff.

I identify the JSON file to the source, it says fine. I do the import of the schema, it loads the schema without incident. I go to "inspect" and it shows me the entities and complex objects all in the correct positions, everything's good.

When I go to "Preview Data" it tells me there are "malformed records" in the source. Well, no, there aren't, and 3 separate online JSON validation engines have confirmed that. The document does not have badly formed records.

Before you ask, I have tried all three document types (single document, one document per line, and array of documents) and all of them get the same response. Allow schema drift and validate schema, neither produces any better results.

Has anyone else run into this? And is there a work-around? Or should I abandon all hope that ADF will ever be able to successfully read in valid JSON?

Comment: Can you please share your Json?

Comment: The contents are proprietary, I will have to anonymize the data before posting. Not sure I will have the time to do that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Trailing CR/LF caused the issue. I've seen this in other engagements, now we build something to trim off the trailing characters and we'll be good to go.